# SDL_ttf will not render

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-ttf

I've got a problem with SDL_ttf, no matter what I do with the TTF_RenderText_Solid function, it refuses to render any text what so ever. My source code is a little bit hefty to put in this question (It's like 150 lines or something) so I'm putting the links to them on Pastie. I want to note, that even though I am putting this thing up it does not entitle you the privilege to screw with and steal my code. It may not be much, but I'll take it as a personal insult. Please just don't do it. Anyway, what's wrong with my code? (If you're going to compile it, just substitute my files with your own random crap)

Also I'd like to note that I'm somewhat new to coding this properly (don't laugh :3) and so my code may look a little, uh, badly organized.

Thanks.

Edit: Oh crap, I forgot that I ripped out my SDL_ttf methods. I'm so sorry! Please try to diagnose without them or add them yourself.

http://pastie.org/1348438 Main.cpp
http://pastie.org/1348440 Main.h

Comment: Tip: Don't render in the event loop, render in the main loop, after the event loop. If you get a gazillion of events, you'll render the stuff a gazillion times per frame.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but don't worry about putting code up.  There's probably someone, somewhere who trawls for code, but most coders on here respect everyone else's work.

Comment: Wait... I'm supposed to tell you why your calls to `TTF_RenderText_Solid` don't work by looking at code that doesn't contain any calls to `TTF_RenderText_Solid`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you've not provided any code that makes `TTF_RenderText_Solid` calls, I can only take shots in the dark.

1. did you call `TTF_Init`?
2. Have you loaded a font? Are you *sure*?
3. What does `TTF_RenderText_Solid` do? "Refuses to render" tells me nothing of value. Does it return `NULL`? Does it return non-`NULL`? If it is returning something, what does that image look like? Have you checked the SDL error string? (I believe SDL_ttf will set it.)

Comment: I'm so sorry for not providing proper code, it's my fault. However I'm going to try all that you suggested and the stuff Ivo Wetzel mentioned.